# Unable to send mail over smtp server, as the 'operation timeout' error occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtpclient, mailmessage

Unable to send mail over smtp server, as the 'operation timeout' error occurs. I have tried almost all the methods given on this website, have tried using another port number and also the client other than gmail, I wonder what the problem is. Following is the attached code segment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 465;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "password");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        newMail.From = new MailAddress("user@gmail.com");
        newMail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    }
    protected void Button_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            newMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBox_to.Text));
            newMail.Subject = TextBox_sub.Text;
            newMail.Body = TextBox_mail.Text;
            smtp.Send(newMail);
            Label_msg.Text = "Message Sent Successfully.";
            Label_msg.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label_msg.Text = "Message not sent <br/>" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have run your code with Port 587 and it worked.
Did it work for you ?

Comment: I tried using port number 587, as I have already mentioned that I used different port number too. But it still doesn't works. It gets timed out. My internet connection is also fast enough, so I don't know why it gets timed out.

Comment: Interesting! As @ZeeshanAjmal tried your code and it worked. Probably try out with differnt Gmail account as well as check Setting of your account, not sure if Google introduce something new!

Comment: I tried different account and also changed all the required settings, but still no use. And the problem is not only with gmail, but all other vendors.!

Comment: @ZeeshanAjmal, Can you please tell me how much time it exactly took to send the e-mail.?

Comment: @user3391912 roughly 3-5 seconds without any attachments

Comment: @ZeeshanAjmal, OK... I thought I need to provide a large timeout value, but after what you are saying its of no use.! By the way what type of internet connection are you using and did you do any modifications with the code like in web.config file or so.?

Comment: @ZeeshanAjmal, And did you use your gmail-id only to run the code? or any other mail provider (Please mention the name).

Comment: @user3391912 i did not make any changes in web.config and i only use my gmail id for testing purpose, no other mail providers

Answer (score 5):

Please try with port number 587.

[image]

Comment: I tried using port number 587, as I have already mentioned that I used different port number too. But it still doesn't works. It gets timed out. My internet connection is also fast enough, so I don't know why it gets timed out.

Answer (score 3):

Placing the line: 
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

above the line:
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@gmail.com", "password");

and using the port number 587 solves the problem.

Thanks everyone, for your contributions.!

Comment: Unbelievable ! when i change to Google Apps account it did not work until i did this!! Thanks Alot